# Looking for a query in IBM QMF

Tags: sql

How can I write a query to get sum of values in Salary field for distinct combination(EmpName,ID) ?

Example;

```
EmpName  Id   Salary
Raju.           1.   2000
Raju.           1.  3000
Vijay.           2.  5000
Vijay.           2.  6000
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select EmpName, ID, sum(salary) from table group by EmpName, ID
```